# SSH can't connect to Google Cloud

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

So, I just do trial GCloud service, and try connect via ssh. At the first time I forget my username of my Mac, so I did it wrong by doing this:

```
doe-MacBook-Pro:Documents does$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine xxxx@111.111.111.111
Warning: Identity file /Users/does/.ssh/google_compute_engine not accessible: No such file or directory.
The authenticity of host '111.111.111.111 (111.111.111.111)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? y
Please type 'yes' or 'no': yes
Warning: Permanently added '111.111.111.111' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

then I know my username, I tried:

```
doe-MacBook-Pro:Documents does$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine does@111.111.111.111
Warning: Identity file /Users/does/.ssh/google_compute_engine not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

and it gives me error. Can you tell me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the ssh username.
Check two things first and we can go from there:

1. Permission: should be readable by you, i.e., at least 0400.
2. File: does it exist at all?

Comment: In your home dir, do `ls -l .ssh`, and see if the file exists and if it does check its permission.

Comment: @Liverpool here's a quick tutorial of file permissions: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Problem SOLVED!**

I forget didn't completed my `gcloud compute ssh project-name` command.
After I finished with the command, it creates file `google_compute_engine`. 
Now I finally can connect to my Google Cloud via SSH.